# Anchor with "computed" URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JS script that appends to the HTML page the pairs: input + anchor

Can I compute the URL before the redirect happens?

Now I have link that looks like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="myFunct();return false;">link</a>
```

and `myFunct` uses `window.location.href` to redirect webpage. The problem with this approach is that I cannot (obviously) CTRL+click on the link for opening goal link in a new tab.

**Details:**

- The link URL is known after obtaining the URL from the server - this operation is very expensive for me and I would like to do that only in case it is absolutely necessary.
- The idea is: user chooses a link, he/she clicks it, url is obtained from server and user is redirected (in the same window or in a new tab if he/she uses CTRL+click)

Thanks!

Comment: Whats the question ? how to compute a link ? or how to make a javascript link open in a new tab ? or something else ? its not very clear

Comment: I have updated the question. I hope it is clear now. I'm sorry for confusion.

Comment: Its still not very clear .... why do you get the URL from the server ? what are you passing to the server ? how are you doing it now ? why is it "Expensive" ?

Comment: Because I'm encrypting the content of input element because I don't have HTTPS available.

Comment: So put your current code in the question and ask for areas of improvement - your question lacks detail ... why is it so hard to include all of the detail in the question when you actually ask it - instead of having us ask questions to get the full picture !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue with pre-computing the link and optimizing the code to make the overhead as low as possible.

Answer (score 3):

Im not entirely certain this is what you are looking for by try giving your anchor an `id`

```
<a href="#" id="mylink">link</a>
```

then just update the `href` attribute to change the new location (perhaps on change on an input ?

```
<input onchange="changeLink(this)" value="http://www.google.com/"/>

function changeLink(elem) {
    var mylink = document.getElementById('mylink');
    mylink.href = this.value;  // you could prepend your value with a domain
}
```

Every time the value in the `input` changes the href will be changed to match

Comment: I can't do this because if a user wants to use a link I need to contact the server with additional information which takes time. That being said the problem is more general.

Comment: @MartyIX you could disable the link until its updated ... why not put all of the details in the question at the start ...

Comment: But to prepare a link takes time (I need to contact the server) and I don't want to do that pro-actively.

Comment: @MartyIX why not set the link from the back end as the page is built - update your question with your actual requirements and detail everything

Answer (score 3):

instead of navigating with the onmousedown, you can just rewrite the href

```
<a href='http://www.google.com' id='computed_link' onmousedown='handleClick()'>Computed Link!!</a>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function handleClick()
{
    document.getElementById('computed_link').href = 'http://www.yahoo.com';
}
</script>
```

Comment: Sure it does.  That was an example of the tool not working... not the script :)
http://tryross.com/travistest/anchor-with-computed-url.html

Comment: Ok, this does work. But not always in every browser. Works fine with chrome but middle mouse click in FF does not. In IE9 middle click and CTRL+click does not work.

Comment: We were not asked for middle click etc, but we can use onmousedown to handle those cases as well.  I have updated the example.

Answer (score 0):

You could create all links on page load

```
function myFunct(link)
{
    return 'http://' + link + '#hash';
}

$('a').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('href', myFunct( $(this).text()) );
});​
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/MpM6Y/

**Update**

You can do the same without jQuery (and more pain) using `var a_list = document.getElementsByTagName('a');` and a loop over `a_list` with `a.href = myFunct( a.innerHTML);`

Comment: You are using jQuery here ... no jQuery tag on the question

Comment: Yes, I know and I was sorry about that. Anyway I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Ok, I added some pure JS elements you need.

Comment: I have updated the question as it was not punctual in details: I don't really know the links in advance.